# Received a possibly malicious .exe, can someone tell me what the attacker intended to do?

Tags: vb.net, exe, decompiling, malware

### I'm not sure what this code does, it is probably malicious.. Please be careful and DO NOT attempt to compile it..

I received a .exe file that probably does something malicious since it was named as **"`.jpg.exe`"**, it had a **fake jpg icon** and it has some stealth options like setting the **`Opacity`** to **`0`**, **`ShowInTaskbar`** to **`False`** and many other settings.

I do know VB, but I'm not experienced enough to tell what it does. Can someone please tell me what this person intended to do to my computer with this program?

### He had these declarations:

```
Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Windows.Forms
```

### This function

```
 Public Shared Function Decrypt(ByVal input As Byte()) As Byte()
            Dim aes As Aes
            Dim bytes As New PasswordDeriveBytes("xdldfklgjdfklgjdfklgjdflgkdfj", New Byte() { &H26, &H16, 11, &H4E })
            Dim stream As New MemoryStream
            aes = New AesManaged With { _
                .Key = bytes.GetBytes((aes.KeySize / 8)), _
                .IV = bytes.GetBytes((aes.BlockSize / 8)) _
            }
            Dim stream2 As New CryptoStream(stream, aes.CreateDecryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            stream2.Write(input, 0, input.Length)
            stream2.Close
            Return stream.ToArray
        End Function
```

I'm assuming this function is meant to decrypt passowrd hashes saved on my computer or something?

### And this is the main function, it is very long so I added it to text file:

http://ninjastormns.my3gb.com/DecompiledVBCode.txt

I'm sorry for posting such an unusual question, but I need to know what this guy was after and this felt like the right place to ask. Thank you.

**Please note that if this code turns out to be malicious as I'm suspecting, I'll remove it once the question is solved to avoid it being reused.**

Comment: I poked around with this for a while because it seemed like an interesting challenge, but alas, I'm no reverse engineering expert. What you seem to have is a long string of bytes representing a compiled assembly that is loaded at run time with `Assembly.Load`. This is all located in the text file. The code you posted in the answer just decrypts the byte array at the top of the text file; it has nothing to do with the actual function of the resulting assembly. You might try your luck with this question on http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not spend much time on this, but the code as shown simply decrypts a large binary blob into an in-memory assembly, then runs it.

Since the `Decrypt` routine itself looked harmless, I copied it into a new project, then ran:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\quarantine\danger.out", Decrypt(New Byte() { &HBC, &H7B, 220, &H4F, &H60, &H56, &HCA, ... }))
```

This wrote the decrypted bytes of the malicious assembly into a file at "C:\quarantine\danger.out". When I did this, my antivirus immediately quarantined the file and flagged it as "Backdoor.Ratenjay", which is listed as a backdoor trojan.

Since I was feeling <s>foolhardy</s> adventurous, I restored the quarantined file and opened it with ILSpy. Among other things, it appears to:

- add a firewall exception for itself using `netsh`
- copy itself to the startup folder
- log keystrokes
- monitor the current foreground window
- connect to a dynamic DNS subdomain to send/receive data
- save downloaded data to the filesystem, then run the downloaded file

The answer to your question would be that the attacker intended to open a backdoor on your computer in order to monitor your system, and to download and run arbitrary commands.